# Unable to retrieve process memory usage Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am trying to write a little utility to retrieve a list of running processes on a computer and the memory being used by each process.

So far I have the following Delphi code:

```
{ ******************************************************************
  Return list of running processes
 ******************************************************************* }
procedure   TGkrTools.GetProcList(var thelist : tstrings);

var
 ExeName : string;
 PSize   : cardinal;
 PID     : cardinal;
 TheLoop : boolean;
 proc    : PROCESSENTRY32;
 hSnap   : HWND;
 pmc     : PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;
 cb      : integer;

begin
 thelist.Clear; // Clear the list on entry
 proc.dwSize := SizeOf(PROCESSENTRY32);//Give proc.dwSize the Size of bytes of PROCESSENTRY32
 hSnap := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
 TheLoop := Process32First(hSnap,proc);
 while Integer(TheLoop) <> 0 do
 begin
  ExeName := ExtractFileName(proc.szExeFile); // Name of process executable
  cb := SizeOf(_PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);
  GetMem(pmc, cb);
  pmc^.cb := cb;
  PID:=proc.th32ProcessID;
  if GetProcessMemoryInfo(PID, pmc, cb) then
  begin
   Psize:=pmc^.WorkingSetSize;
  end
  else
  begin
   Psize:=0;
  end;
  Thelist.Add(ExeName + ' ' + IntToStr(Psize)+ ' ' + IntToStr(PID));
  TheLoop := Process32Next(hSnap,proc);//Looper is oposite Zero until there is a program to process by this function
 end;
end;
```

I successfully retrieve the "ExeName" and "PID" but when I execute the GetProcessMemoryInfo function, the call returns "false".

Any ideas on what is wrong in my code?
I'm running this on a 32 bit Windows 7 machine.

Thanks in advance,

Gudfinnur Kristjansson

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return when you get FALSE for `GetProcessMemoryInfo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683219.aspx) carefully. The first parameter is a process handle rather than a process ID. You need to call `OpenProcess` to get a process handle from the process ID. The documentation also says:

> The handle must have the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right and the PROCESS_VM_READ access right.

Make sure that you request those access rights when calling `OpenProcess`.

When you are done with the handle, close it with `CloseHandle`. Again, read the documentation closely.

Do note that your current code leaks the dynamic memory that you allocate. There is actually no need to allocate memory dynamically. Rather than declaring a `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`, pointer to the struct, declare a variable of type `PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`. Then the memory can be allocated automatically on the stack.

One final point to make is that the documentation also tells you to call `GetLastError` if the function fails. Do make sure that you do this to try to diagnose any failures.